# What to do about Missing values for Multivariate regression analysis

Tags: regression, statistical-inference, machine-learning

I am required to perform multivariate analysis on all countries in the World bank database regarding digital divide. I am confused becasue when I look at factors such as School enrollment, there are many missing values. For example, year 2005 will have value but year 2001 will be missing the data value. My question is that how can I then perform regression analysis multivariate, since same is the case with all the variables. Please help.

thanks,
choken

Comment: Basically, you can try to impute the missing values using various methods or simply discard the incomplete observations. It depends, among other things, on the reason why the data is missing in the first place.